# Is there a word to describe the feeling of being transfixed out of horror?

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

Could not find an existing duplicate question, but this may be due to not know how to describe the word/feeling!

For example, given the following sentence:

> Francis could not look away from the blood-drenched vampire. The blood-soaked clothes and shimmering fangs were X

And X is specifically drawing upon the fact that the appearance is horrifying, horrible, scary, etc.

Similar words that come to mind but are generic in their motivation: hypnotic, transfixing

First question on this Stack so apologies if poor formatting!

Comment: Your own suggestion 'transfixed' (or transfixing) is as good as the others. [A thesaurus lookup on transfix](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/transfix) gives a lot more. None of them are exactly 'transfix' _and_ 'horror', but many are related to fear. 'scared stiff' is exactly it, but not a present participle which is the slot you gave.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the Oxford online dictionary the verb [to petrify](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/petrify) means by its primary definition

> Change (organic matter) into a stony substance by encrusting or replacing it with a calcareous, siliceous, or other mineral deposit.

However it has the secondary, originally metaphorical, definition of

> Make (someone) so frightened that they are unable to move

The the present paticiple of **to petrify** is **petrifying** which would fit well into your sentence.

Comment: Ah, if only there was a mix between @Ibf's 'stunned' suggestion and this! I think I am going to mark your answer as correct as it did answer my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: True, but quite the same as *transfixed*, which fits the context.

Comment: @Kris - Hmm, you can definitely be transfixed by the beauty of something, I'm not sure I've ever heard of someone being petrified by beauty, other than in the sense of being too scared to talk to them.

Comment: @kris That is an alternative but the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transfix) definition of **transfix** includes transfixtion with horror, wonder, or astonishment whereas the dictionary definition of **petrify** includes only petrification by fear in the metaphorical sense.

Answer (score 2):

As in:

The blood-soaked clothes and shimmering fangs **stunned** him.

stunned  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stun)

> - to shock or overwhelm
> - to surprise or astound

Comment: See my comment at BoldBen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an issue with the correct answer, but I don't think "petrifying" actually scans very well.  I'm surprised nobody mentioned:

[Mesmerising](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mesmerizing)

```
Capturing one's complete attention as if by magic.
‘a mesmerizing stare’
```

Comment: *Mesmerising* doesn't capture the element of horror, but to be fair, neither do the OP's examples along that vein.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **horror-struck** (or **horror-stricken**). The word corresponds exactly to the question in the title (i.e., "the feeling of being transfixed from horror"), although your example sentence is slightly different in that it asks for a word that describes the source of horror.

So although we couldn't say that the "bload-soaked clothes were horror-striking", we could say that "Francis was horror-struck by the bload-soaked clothes".

[horror-struck](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horror-struck)

> horrified so as to be overwhelmed or incapacitated

Answer (score 0):

**Frozen** also carries the sense of "blood running cold with fear"

Comment: Please provide a source for your answer.

Comment: Hi rhararg, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a relevant published definition of *frozen* (linked to the source) and say why it suits the context. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)